# "vobjtovarid4: error #F: I could not find the requsted var (or dimvar) in the file!"

Tags: r

I am trying to get specific variables out of a NETcdf file using ncdf4 and the ncvar_get() function. When I open the file and print() it I can see the available variables but when I try get them out I get

> "vobjtovarid4: error #F: I could not find the requsted var (or dimvar)
>   in the file!"
>
> [1] "var (or dimvar) name: precipitation"
>
> [1] "file name: /Users/megmccann/Documents/Prec data/Prec
>   data/cru_ts3.24.1901.2015.pre.dat.nc"
>
> Error in vobjtovarid4(nc, varid, verbose = verbose, allowdimvar =
>   TRUE) :    Variable not found

Here is my script:

> prec.ex.nc <- nc_open("/Users/megmccann/Documents/Prec data/Prec data/cru_ts3.24.1901.2015.pre.dat.nc")
>
> print(prec.ex.nc)

File /Users/megmccann/Documents/Prec data/Prec data/cru_ts3.24.1901.2015.pre.dat.nc (NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC):

```
 1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    double pre[lon,lat,time]   
        long_name: precipitation
        units: mm/month
        correlation_decay_distance: 450
        _FillValue: 9.96920996838687e+36
        missing_value: 9.96920996838687e+36

 3 dimensions:
    lon  Size:720
        long_name: longitude
        units: degrees_east
    lat  Size:360
        long_name: latitude
        units: degrees_north
    time  Size:1380   *** is unlimited ***
        long_name: time
        units: days since 1900-1-1
        calendar: gregorian

9 global attributes:
    Conventions: CF-1.4
    title: CRU TS3.24 Precipitation
    institution: Data held at British Atmospheric Data Centre, RAL, UK.
    source: Run ID = 1610031104
```

Data generated by BADC from:
pre.1609291528.dtb
        history: Wed 19 Oct 2016 10:53:41 BST : User ianharris : Program makegridsauto.for called by update.for
        references: Information on the data is available at http://badc.nerc.ac.uk/data/cru/
        comment: Access to these data is available to any registered CEDA user.
        contact: BADC 
        acknowledgement: This update was supported by NERC NCAS and by NERC SMURPHS (NE/N006348/1)

> precipitation <- ncvar_get(prec.ex.nc, "precipitation")
>
> longitude <- ncvar_get(prec.ex.nc, "longitude")
>
> latitude <- ncvar_get(prec.ex.nc, "latitude")
>
> t <- ncvar_get(prec.ex.nc, "time")

Where I get the error code for all variables except time?
I used the exact same code for a different NETcdf file for Temperature_anomalies and it worked fine?

Comment: Is it because you are trying to use the long names? Try "lon" instead of "longitude". The long and short name for "time" is the same which might explain why "time" works...

Comment: was the error spelling _requsted_ or _requested_ (like in https://github.com/PecanProject/pecan/issues/725)?

Comment: I ran across the same error while using the raster package - I was unable to reproduce it using the ncdf4 package. Rather than rewrite this question I created a new one with a reproducible example and sample file https://stackoverflow.com/q/67944884/199217