# r ncdf4 "I could not find the requsted var!"

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, ncdf4

I am getting a 'could not find the requested var' error, even though the variable name is valid - it works with other netcdf libraries - including NCO, the R netcdf4 library, and Panoply:

This example uses a file called [test2.nc](https://arizona.box.com/v/test-netcdf-file):

This works as expected:

```r
library(ncdf4)
nc <- nc_open('test2.nc')
v <- ncvar_get(nc, 'biomass')
image(v)
nc_close(nc)
```

This does not work:

```r
library(raster)
r <- raster('test2.nc', 'biomass')
#> Loading required namespace: ncdf4
#> [1] "vobjtovarid4: error #F: I could not find the requsted var (or dimvar) in the file!"
#> [1] "var (or dimvar) name: crs"
#> [1] "file name: test2.nc"
#> Warning in .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...): NAs
#> introduced by coercion
#> Error in if (band > nbands(r)) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United States.1252  
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252  
#>  tz       America/Phoenix             
#>  date     2021-06-11                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  backports     1.2.1   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  cli           2.3.1   2021-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  codetools     0.2-16  2018-12-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  crayon        1.4.1   2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fansi         0.4.2   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.1.1 2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  knitr         1.31    2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  lattice       0.20-41 2020-04-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.0   2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  ncdf4         1.17    2019-10-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  pillar        1.5.1   2021-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  raster      * 3.4-5   2020-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.6   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  reprex        2.0.0   2021-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  rgdal         1.5-23  2021-02-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rlang         0.4.10  2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rmarkdown     2.7     2021-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sp          * 1.4-5   2021-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  styler        1.3.2   2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tibble        3.1.0   2021-02-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  utf8          1.2.1   2021-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  vctrs         0.3.6   2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  withr         2.4.1   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  xfun          0.20    2021-01-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#> 
#> [1] C:/Users/David/Documents/lib/R
#> [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library
```

Comment: This appears to be a data problem. Have you checked if the file is cf complaint? Uploading here is likely to point towards the problem https://cfconventions.org/compliance-checker.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `rast` function from the `terra` package. It creates a `SpatRaster` object. You can convert the object to a `raster` later using the `raster` function. However, most of the functionalities you want to use in the `raster` package can probably be achieved by using the `terra` package. So just stay in the `SpatRaster` class is probably fine.

```
library(terra)
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

r <- rast("test2.nc")
r
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 72, 120, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
# extent      : -115, -110, 30, 33  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source      : test2.nc 
# varname     : biomass (biomass) 
# name        :     biomass 
# unit        : Mg ha-1 y-1 
r2 <- raster(r)
r2
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 72, 120, 8640  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
# extent     : -115, -110, 30, 33  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : test2.nc 
# names      : biomass 
# zvar       : biomass
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `raster` package, you have to use the `varname` argument like this

`raster("test2.nc", varname="biomass")`

But since the example file only has a single variable, you can just do:

`raster("test2.nc")`

With `terra`, as shown by @www, you can do

`rast("test2.nc")`

or

`rast("test2.nc", "biomass")`

If there are multiple sub-datasets you might do

`sds("test2.nc")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this  (but do it before you close the connection).

```
nc <- nc_open('test2.nc')
biomass.in2 <- ncvar_get(nc, "biomass")
dim(biomass.in2)
[1] 120  72

r <- raster(biomass.in2)
#-----------------
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 120, 72, 8640  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01388889, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 7.65493  (min, max)

> summary(r@data@values)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  0.000   0.000   1.844   2.142   3.865   7.655    1425 
> str(r)
Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ name        : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
  .. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
  .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf
  .. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ nbands      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
  .. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
  .. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 0
  .. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 0
  .. .. ..@ driver      : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
  ..@ data    :Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ values    : num [1:8640] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
  .. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
  .. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ attributes: list()
  .. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ min       : num 0
  .. .. ..@ max       : num 7.65
  .. .. ..@ band      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ unit      : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ names     : chr ""
  ..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
  ..@ title   : chr(0) 
  ..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
  .. .. ..@ xmin: num 0
  .. .. ..@ xmax: num 1
  .. .. ..@ ymin: num 0
  .. .. ..@ ymax: num 1
  ..@ rotated : logi FALSE
  ..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
  .. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
  ..@ ncols   : int 72
  ..@ nrows   : int 120
  ..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
  ..@ history : list()
  ..@ z       : list()
```